# php logical operator comparison evaluation

Tags: php

here is what i'm trying to achieve:

> if $x is either of these 3 values: 100, 200 or 300 - do something

I'm doing this:

```
if($x==("100"||"200"||"300"))  
{  
  //do something  
}
```

but `//do something` is executed even if `$x` is `400`

I noticed that this works:

```
if($x=="100"||$x=="200"||$x=="300")  
{  
  //do something  
}
```

How is the first block of code different from the second block of code? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is because the result of the expression:

```
('100' || '200' || '300')
```

is always `TRUE` because the expression contains at least one truthy value.

So, the RHS of the expression is `TRUE`, while the LHS is a truthy value, therefore the entire expression evaluates to `TRUE`. **The reason why this is happening is because of the `==` operator**, which does loose comparison. If you used `===`, the resulting expression would always be `FALSE`. (unless of course the value of `$x` is false-y.)

Let's analyze this:

Assuming `$x` equal `'400'`:

```
  ($x == ('100'||'200'||'300'))

//  ^            ^
// true         true
```

Make sense now?

Bottom line here is: **This is the wrong way of comparing 3 values against a common variable**.

My suggestion is that you use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if(in_array($x, array('100', '200', '300')) {
   //do something...
}
```

Comment: i don't know who downvoted him but i guess it was because his initial response was something else. my earlier comment was directed to his initial response.

Comment: thank you for your response jacob - that explanation certainly helps a lot!

Comment: @Gunner: initial response was very far from answer. That' was completely a post instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

you can take  all values in array it is working Perfectly.

```
$x=400;

if(in_array($x, array('100', '200', '300'))) {
    echo $x.'is in array';
} else {
    echo $x.'is not in array';
}
```